# Is it possible to programmatically invoke "select all" then "copy" on a UIWebView on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, copy

I want to provide a copy button where the user can quickly copy the text from a UIWebView. When I hold my finger and move it to the edges, I have no problem selecting all of the text, and then hitting copy. Is there a way to programmatically do this?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't try it, but this should work to get the already selected text:

```
NSString *webViewString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function (){return window.getSelection().toString();})();"];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:webViewString]; //Copy to pasteboard
NSString *pasteBoardString = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string]; //Paste from pasteboard
```

Just search for another javascript snippet to select all... You should find one very quickly.

Comment: I tried this, and I cannot paste the contents afterwards in a plain UITextView or rich-text Mail window.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text in the UIWebView with some javascript:

```
NSString *innerText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

It will give you the HTML text, including tags and everything...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, the whole point is not to get the html tags and just the content

Comment: If you use innerText instead of innerHTML, you get the text and not the HTML tags. It works very well.